# Group by only second Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to only group by the second column so there are no duplicates:

```
ID | Name
__________
1  | Test1
2  | Test2
3  | Test3
4  | Test2
5  | Test1
6  | Test4
```

So I only want to show:

```
ID | Name
__________
1  | Test1
2  | Test2
3  | Test3
6  | Test4
```

I tried using Distinct and group by with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using the `MIN` aggregate:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21393/1)

Comment: Cheers, I knew it was something easy :) Thanks

Comment: @Stan -- np, glad we could help!

Comment: Long day, couldn't use row_number() as its sql server 2000

Answer (score 2):

When you group you have to choose what to do with the values in the other field:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Name
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Would return each name and the lowest ID.

If you just want the distinct Name's you'd have to not select the ID field.